# Seaborn heatmap colors are reversed

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm generating a heatmap from a pandas dataframe using a code that looks like this on my apple computer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,14))
sns.set(font_scale=1.4)
sns_plot = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, linewidths=.5, fmt='g', ax=ax).set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax.set_ylabel('Product')
ax.set_xlabel('Manufacturer')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')

fig.savefig('output.png')
```

And I get a heatmap looking like this:

[image]

I then put my code in a docker container with an ubuntu image and I install the same version of seaborn. The only difference is that I need to add a matplotlib configuration so that TCL doesn't scream:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

And I get a heatmap that looks like this (I use the same code and the same pandas dataframe):

[image]

I'm unable to find why the color gradient is inverted and would love to hear if you have any idea.

Thank you !

Comment: Make sure that you are using the same seaborn version in both cases, the default colormap changed lately. It looks a bit weird nevertheless as the colors shown in the colorbar are not present in the heatmap image (as if the scaling changed).

Comment: oh, but the same is true for the first image - that's because the images are cropped.

Comment: yes sorry the images are cropped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default colormap has changed to `'rocket'` for sequential data with 0.8 release of seaborn, see [the release notes](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-8-0-july-2017). The colormap looks this way now:
[image]
You can always use the `cmap` argument and specify which colormap you prefer to use. For example, to get the pre-0.8 colormap for non-divergent data use: `cmap=sns.cubehelix_palette(light=.95, as_cmap=True)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there an easy way of saying that the lowest values get the brightest colors meanwhile the highest values get the darkest colors ?

Comment: If you want to reverse a colormap you can append `_r` to its name - so in the case of `'rocket'` colormap you would just do: `cmap='rocket_r'`

Comment: What name should be used to obtain old colormap, if one wants to regenerate a heatmap plot with new data, but needs it to look like the old one?

Comment: Before 0.8 non-divergent data were plotted with `sns.cubehelix_palette(light=.95, as_cmap=True)` - you can pass this to the `cmap` argument. I've updated the answer now.